# how to double Edit DataGridCell (or How to Edit a DataGridCell after Edit)

Tags: datagrid, edit, datagridcell

actual situation 
i have a `Datagrid` with some `TemplateColumns` if somebody going to edit a `DataGridCell` a Window pops up where the user can do his changes, after pressing the save button my window disposed and only the `DataGridCell` is selected but if he now want's to Reedit this `DataGridCell` he must first change the selection to an other DataGridCell

this is my `DataGrid.BeginningEdit`

```
    private void _BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        var list = dg.CurrentCell.Item as IList;
        new DetailV() { Content = list[dg.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex] }.ShowDialog();

        dg.CancelEdit();
    }
```

i think maybe my `DataGridCell`is already in Edit-mode but way because i already  use the `CancelEdit()` to end all Edit Operations do i miss something?

Comment: Try to temporary save your cell's current value into a variable, then handle SelectedCellIndexChanged event, check if user leave cell without saving, set cell's value by the temporary variable

Comment: @DoanCuong the "problem" (normal DataGrid behavior) occurs if the user doesn't change the cell between his edits

Comment: How about use DatagridCellDoubleClick event to open edit window in stead of enter edit mode in DataGridCell?

Comment: @DoanCuong mhh but now the user must everytime he want's to edit and reedit DoubleClick on my `DataGridCell` i think this isn't user friendly either. i also found out that's editing be F2 has the same strange behavior like the click method to start the Edit Method